# Update Column values for the files inside a folder in Sharepoint Library using CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, console-application

How to update columns inside a folder in sharepoint library using CSOM. I have a Document library in which I create folders programatically and copy files from another library into the created folder.I want to update the columns against each copied file inside the folder using C# in console application.

I am using

```
Folder folder = destList.RootFolder;
FolderCollection listfold = destList.RootFolder.Folders;
List<string> folders = new List<string>();
ctx.Load(listfold);
ctx.Load(folder);
ctx.Load(destList.RootFolder.Files);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
foreach (Folder f in listfold)
{
  if (f.Name == prevMonth)
   {
     ctx.Load(f.Files);
     ctx.ExecuteQuery();
     FileCollection fcoll = f.Files;
     foreach (File file in fcoll)
      {
        //here InvoiceNo is name of my column inside document set in 
       //destination library. doc["InvoiceNo"] is item from source library 
       //from where file is being copied.

   file.Properties.FieldValues.Add("InvoiceNo",doc["InvoiceNo"].ToString());                                      
 }
```

kindly help me on how to update column values inside a document folder in a sharepoint library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there ;).
To update values of sharepoint column you need to pass by an [ListItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.listitem.aspx)
You can find this object with the property : [ListItemAllFields](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.file.listitemallfields.aspx) of your SharePoint File.

You can try something like in your code :

```
foreach (File file in fcoll)
{
   //Load the SP ListITem of the File
   var item = file.ListItemAllFields;
   ctx.Load(item);
   ctx.ExecuteQuery();// Not sure if this is needed

   //Update value of the ListItem
   item["InvoiceNo"] = doc["InvoiceNo"].ToString();
   item.Update();
   //Save to SharePoint
   ctx.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

Hope this will help you